# Why is my express delete request not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

When making this delete request through postman on my localhost everything works how it should. But when making the request on my React.js client side it does not send the request.

Here is the api request

```
router.delete("/deletetransaction/:id", getUser, async (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.transaction != null) {
    res.user.transaction.remove(req.body.transaction);
  }

  try {
    const updatedUser = await res.user.save();
    res.json(updatedUser);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

This is the request I am trying to make on my client side using axios

```
async function deleteTransaction(transactionDetails) {
    const userId = localStorage.getItem("id");
    const id = transactionDetails.id;
    try {
      await axios
        .delete(
          `https://expensetrackerbytim.herokuapp.com/expensetracker/deletetransaction/${userId}`,
          {
            transaction: {
              id: transactionDetails.id,
              transactionAmount: `${transactionDetails.transactionAmount}`,
              transactionType: `${transactionDetails.transactionType}`,
            },
          },
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
          }
        )
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.err(err);
        });
      dispatch({
        type: ACTIONS.DELETE_TRANSACTION,
        payload: id,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: ACTIONS.ERROR_TRANSACTION,
        payload: err.res,
      });
    }
  }
```

I have triple checked that I am passing through all the correct information. The request works in postman also in REST client extension. At this point I am thinking of updating the transaction database whenever my state updates because my state updates correctly but when I refresh the browser obviously the data is back.

Comment: I have a addTransaction post request that is the exact same format other than its a POST request and instead of remove() it is push(). And that request works fine

Comment: have you checked for errors in the browser console? have you put any console.log's in the server to see what it's receiving in the request?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Axios wiki](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-method-aliases), for delete request, body should be inside config object.
[image: Axisos Doc - https://github.com/axios/axios#request-method-aliases]

Sh, to account for that, your method should be rewritten as something like this :

```
await axios
    .delete(
      `https://expensetrackerbytim.herokuapp.com/expensetracker/deletetransaction/${userId}`,
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        data: {
          transaction: {
            id: transactionDetails.id,
            transactionAmount: `${transactionDetails.transactionAmount}`,
            transactionType: `${transactionDetails.transactionType}`,
          },
        }
      }
    )
```